# How to get the data from BoundField?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to get the number 2 from my `BoundField` object, that's problematic because it is not iterable or doesnt support indexing.

`<BoundField value=2 errors=None>`

Can someone please help?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/boundfield/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.value

Does `BoundField.value()` not work?

Comment: That actually worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! please consider upvoting / checkmarking answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/boundfield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.value

You can access a `BoundField`'s value with `BoundField.value()`.